# How can i enlarge an image in a card and reduce the empty space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a card with an image, and next to it is a banner. I use `col-lg-8` and `col-lg-4`. The problem is that there is too much empty space between the card (which also has `padding-right: 20px`) and the banner, like in this screenshot:[image: ss]

I'd like to remove all that white space and just leave `padding-right`: 20px (or `margin-right`) between the card and the banner. So I want to extend the width of the image like in the picture (up to the example red line),because the size of the orange banner is `fixed` and I don't want to resize it. So I would like the enlarged card, some white space (`20 px`) between card and banner, and then the fixed banner. Consequently the only "empty whitespace" must be that of 20px between the card and the banner, to adhere to the bootstrap grid in col-lg-8 and col-lg-4, and to have no other whitespace.

How can I enlarge the card leaving `col-lg-8` and `col-lg-4` the same? (I also tried `col-lg-9`, but I don't prefer it because the card is too big).

**My attempts at a solution (which looked apparently correct, but aren't):**

- **WIDHT IMAGE 105%:** I tried applying a `105% widht` to the card and the problem seemed to be solved, but when i make the window smaller then the card joins the banner (or overlaps) leaving no padding-right.
- **WIDHT COLUMNS 75% and 25%:** I tried changing the width of the columns. I changed `.col-lg-8` from `width: 66.66666667%` to `75%`. Then I changed `.col-lg-4` from `width: 25%`, so the total was `100%`. Here too the problem seemed to be solved, but several people advised me against changing the column width of Bootstrap and told me that it is not very professional.
- **REMOVE TEXT-ALIGN: RIGHT:** I tried removing `.banner {text-align: right;}`. In this way the banner approaches the card, but creates an empty space to its right (to the right of the banner). I don't know if this is correct. You observe another [screenshot](https://ibb.co/WP7PFCq)

Here is [the code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Danty23/pen/mdzYNKJ) where you can test better. What is the best solution to what I ask above? Thank you, all, in advance!!! Thanks!

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-pc {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-primapagina {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

.banner {
  text-align: right;
}

.height1 {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-pc">

    <div class="container-primapagina col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col 8 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col 4 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest to set img tag width of 100% but it will also increase the height so if you don’t like it, you can manually set width as per your preference.

Comment: I can't comprehend what you are wanting. `padding-right: 20px` creates a 20-pixel-wide gap of whitespace. Additionally, because the right orange banner is narrower than 33% of the total width, the declaration `.banner {text-align: right;}` is creating whitespace between the card and banner.

Comment: @Nexo I tried to set the width with 105% widht and it's ok, but I have the problem described in the question when I make the window smaller

Comment: @TimR I want to extend the width of the image like in the photo. I want NOT to change the width of the banner because it's a fixed size. I want a small empty space between the card and the banner (hence the padding-right 20px). Yes, maybe I was wrong to use .banner {text-align: right;}, but I noticed that I don't use it, so the banner leaves an empty space to its right so https://ibb.co/WP7PFCq . How can I fix? Thank you

Comment: @TimR *but I noticed that IF I don't use it

Comment: The banner is a fixed size inside a container that is too wide. You cannot overlap columns that are designed to be proportional widths. This is not a good use for these columns.

Comment: I believe you're missing the bigger picture: the image occupies exactly all of the column width minus the `20px` right padding. Most of that perceived space is coming from the right column, because you chose to align the banner to the right. What is it that you expect? The image to go out of the column? Also, if you increase the image's width, do you also want its height to increase? Or do you want it distorted? Or cropped? You're asking about increasing an element's size without defining what exactly drives its new size and behavior. This makes your question *off-topic*.

Comment: The fix for your problem is to remove `text-align: right` from `.banner`. Another being giving it a dark background color (e.g: `#233`).

Comment: @tao No. This is not the solution. In my question I wrote that I have already tried this, but it doesn't solve. This brings the banner closer to the card, but creates an empty space to its right (to the right of the banner). Also, you want to try to enlarge the banner width, I don't want/can't, because the banner size is fixed (Google's fixed size). Do you have other ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want the bootstrap column behavior there. Why are you using them if you don't want it? Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/bpcxz9ny/) what you want?

Comment: @tao Exact. I don't want the column behavior there. But I want it when I zoom out the window to get the tablet and smartphone version. I used col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 because I needed the same card for the large screen (desktop), medium and small (tablet and smartphone). So, as far as I understand from the various answers, I don't have to use the column for the Desktop version, however, IMPORTANT I add that: I would need the behavior of the column on the same card for the smartphone and tablet version (but not Desktop). What does your code do? Thank you

Comment: The *"behavior of the column for the smartphone and tablet"* is literally `width: 100%`. The only thing I don't like about what I posted above is it distorts the image, which is unprofessional. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2m9uozkc/)'s a cleaner approach. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I realized what you're intentions are. You want the banner on the right side to remain a fixed width while the left card fills the remaining space. You should *not* be using columns. You should be using flex. The container `container-pc` is already a flex container, so simply remove the column classes. The columns are intended to not flex but maintain proportional width. The columns can't overlap. You are using the wrong tool.

If you were to change the proportions from 8:4 to 9:3, the banner overflows because it is the wrong size for the column.

I recommend reading through the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/) to learn how to use Bootstrap while avoiding redundancy and linking unnecessary stylesheets and JavaScript files. A hindrance to your layout being responsive on narrow screens is that your images are using fixed sizes.

The following examples show:

- columns at 9:3 ratio
- removing the column classes to use the container flexbox
- applying Bootstrap's `d-flex` class to the container
- applying `d-md-flex` to the container and `object-fit-cover` to the card background image

  - (`d-md-flex` adds `display: flex` at the medium breakpoint)
  - (`object-fit-cover` maintains the image aspect ratio and clips off the edges instead of squishing the image as the container shrinks)

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-pc {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-primapagina {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

.banner {
  text-align: right;
}

.height1 {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>


</head>

<body>

<p class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">d-md-flex &amp; object-fit-cover classes</p>
  <div class="container-pc d-md-flex">
    <div class="container-primapagina">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1 object-fit-cover" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

<p class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">d-flex class</p>
  <div class="container-pc d-flex">
    <div class="container-primapagina">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

<p class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">Without column classes</p>
  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="container-primapagina">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col 8 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col 4 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
  </div>


<p class="text-center mt-4 mb-1">Columns 9:3</p>
  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="container-primapagina col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner col-lg-3">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col 8 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col 4 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see you removed the columns. I hadn't considered deleting the columns, because as you can see from my HTML code ("container-frontpage col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8" ), I also use the column on smartphones and tablets with col-12 and col -md-8. If I delete the columns, my whole site breaks when I scale. How could I use your solution and also still use it for smartphones and tablets when I resize the window? Thank you

Comment: If I try to use your code and resize the window for tablets, the orange banner appears below the tab. It should appear next to it. Previously, with col-md-8, I would make the card smaller and automatically the orange banner would appear on the side. Now with your code, having no columns, I can't do that anymore. Do you have any ideas how I can fix this? I've always used columns. Thank you :)

Comment: Your answer is the one that comes closest to what I want, indeed, you have practically solved the problem, but at the same time you have created others problems, because I can no longer manage the smartphone and tablet versions with columns. Is there any solution to tailor your answer to what I need? Thank you

Comment: @Folidex23 Try resizing your question example. For all three demonstrations, I see the banner wrapping at less than around 990px. I noticed that `container-pc` loses `display: flex` at this breakpoint. Try using the class `d-flex` on that container. You may also want to try the class `object-fit-cover` on the card background image.

Comment: This code is just a small part of my code.I have not entered the other Media Queries.Using D-FLEX in the container-pc html,then the orange banner stays near the card when I resize for the Tablet version.But your solution causes me various concerns, there is something about your idea that escapes me.Considering your solution is to remove the columns,now I have some difficulty in handling the columnless content. Question: Does your solution apply correctly to the Desktop version only?Or can I also use it for the Tablet and Smartphone versions?Wouldn't it be better to use col-md? Thank you

Comment: @Folidex23 I've edited my answer to show the `d-flex` examples. You should read the [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/) documentation and learn how to add responsive breakpoints instead of expecting me to do it for you.

Comment: But I know how to add breakpoints, in fact I'm using several correctly both through the columns and through the media queries setting the dimensions. What I was saying is something else and maybe you don't understand what I'm saying. I'm saying that with your solution, I solve the problem of the question, but at the same time your solution causes me other problems that I didn't have before

Comment: @Folidex23 Each of Bootstrap's layouts have breakpoints but you are using only columns. Heck, I suppose you could use columns at the lower breakpoints and flexbox at the higher breakpoints. There are multiple tools available and you should learn how to use them. It's like saying you don't want to pick up the screwdriver because you're already using the hammer.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I know how to do it correctly.Yes, the idea is to use the flexbox at the top breakpoints and columns at the bottom breakpoints. I find yours, the best solution, for now, even if,as I said,it causes me some headaches (don't get angry ha ha ha :)). I deleted col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 from the container "container-frontpage" and now the desktop version works fine.But I have problems for the smartphone and tablet version, because for "container-firstpage" I have to manually add Media Queries because I no longer have the columns.Did you mean this?Thank you

Comment: @Folidex23 Okay, fine. I'll hold your hand and add the necessary appropriate classes to make it responsive. As I've tried to show and Nexo stated in his answer, Bootstrap contains every CSS declaration and there's no reason to write your own CSS; just add the appropriate class. That's why the Bootstrap stylesheets are a quarter of a megabyte.

Comment: Just to confirm if I understood correctly: what do flex-column and flex-md-row allow me to do in my case? Thank you

Comment: @Folidex23 I got to thinking about it and realized my suggestion was essentially declaring the defaults. I took another look at the docs and saw that to apply flexbox at the medium breakpoint, just add the `.d-md-flex` class (I edited my answer again to reflect this.) Flexbox can be confusing because `flex-direction: column` means the blocks are stacked on top of each other to create a column (the default action of block-level elements) whereas flexbox's default value `flex-direction: row` puts the block-level elements in one row.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, screenshot, and comments, it seems like this is what you're looking for. Since the image is set to cover and in the background of the card, it's a bit cleaner matching the columns of your grid.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-pc {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

.image-bground {
  background-image: url("https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-right:20px;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-pc">

  <div class="container-primapagina col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 image-bground">
    <div class="card text-bg-dark">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner col-lg-4">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-pc">
  <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col 8 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col 4 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. There is too much empty space between the card and the orange banner in your code. I just want a padding-right of 20px as empty space. For this reason I was trying to enlarge the image a bit. Can you review your code please?  Also I added more details in the question. Perhaps they will be useful to you. Thank you

Comment: The orange banner on the right simply isn't a wide enough image to fill the width of col-lg-4.  You mentioned you want a padding-right of 20px, but it sounds like you mean a margin-right? I've updated the code.

Comment: I know the orange banner isn't wide enough to fill the width of col-lg-4. The problem is just that. Your current solution, is similar to mine that I encountered in point 3 of my solution attempts. Using margin-right:20px is a little better, but it's not what I was looking for. There is some space to the right of the orange banner. To avoid this, I had just used text-align: right and wanted to enlarge the image. Can you enlarge the card and remove that space to the right of the banner? In the question I asked to enlarge the card. Thank you

Comment: For example, I'm trying to use margin-right: 30px and width: 104% for the card, and then text-align: right for the banner. It seems like an "almost sufficient" solution, because when I shrink the window the card doesn't join the bar and the breakpoint to scale to Medium Devices applies when there is still enough space between the card and the banner. Can this solution be correct or is it unprofessional? I'm sure there is something better

Comment: Trying to understand what it is you're after... So you want 20px between the left and right images, to adhere to the bootstrap grid at col-lg-8 and col-lg-4, and to not have any white space on the end of the grid row?

Comment: Exact. The only "white space" must be 20px between card and banner. I found the solution described in the comment above, but I don't know if it is very professional. I hope for a better solution than an expert like you. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you have two possible solutions; #1, shrink the overall container so that it allows the orange image to match (at least more closely) with the size of the column its in; #2, enlarge the orange image so it matches the current column size. Any other solutions (that I can think of) would not adhere to the rules that I stated above.

Comment: @Jack I understand. I thought there were other solutions. The one I used (margin-right: 30px and width: 104% for the card, and then text-align: right for the banner) is very wrong or could it be fine?

Comment: @Jack I meant text-align: center, excuse me

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didn't help me. Thank you all the same :)

Answer (score 0):

**CHECK OUTPUT ON FULL SCREEN**

- To be honest what you were trying to achieve cab be done purely with bootstrap.
- You have to understand that bootstrap works on grid 12.
- You are directly using `col-`, its' ideal to to follow below code structure.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

- You can see my code, I do not even using a single css below, if you want to change container width you can change it in `.container` class or replace with new class.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 ps-0">
        <div class="card text-bg-dark">
          <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 pe-0">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner" class="img-fluid h-100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9" style="background-color: aqua;" ;="">Col 9 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;="">Col 3 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**PURE HTML CSS APPROACH**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}

.card .card-left {
  position: relative;
}

.card .card-left .card-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.card .card-left img {
  height: 453px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-left">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" alt="...">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-right">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner" class="img-fluid h-100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looking at your solution and comparing it to the colored bar created as a guide, I see that there is some space left to the left of the card and then some space to the right of the orange banner. So you've left equal space at the two margins. I've never faced a problem like this and I don't know. Is it right that all the content (card+banner) is 12 columns but has smaller dimensions than 12 columns? Are those two spaces left and right a professional solution or are they just a stage/patch on the problem? Thank you

Comment: Do you know about ```gutters``` in bootstrap., Its just ```padding-left``` and ```padding-right```, ```15px```.

Comment: And to remove that space see, I have updated code, ```pe-0``` and ```ps-0```, to respective ```column```.

Comment: I'm away from home now. I'll answer you in a few hours. Thank you

Comment: One question please: without pe-0, there was some empty space on the right side of the orange banner. By applying your pe-0 the empty space disappears. Does this mean that the orange banner gets bigger in size (automatically in width)?

Comment: The space was occupied by 15px off padding to right, and as soon as we apply ‘’’pe-0’’’ it give roam of 15 px to that column’s content.

Comment: Yes, but this causes the orange banner to widen slightly. It's not good, because Google's orange banner must remain with a fixed size. 
The idea of ​​your code is right, but as I said in the question the orange banner has to be fixed in size

Comment: Can you use pure css solution?

Comment: I have one for it so, if you want I can provide that.

Comment: By pure you mean without using Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm going crazy looking for new solutions. I tried your solution, but also other solutions of the question. The one that seems most valid is Tim R's solution (although it doesn't convince me 100% because I had to remove all the Bootstrap columns and I have to redo everything by hand using Media Query). So if you have another solution and you don't get bored of showing it to me, I'll be glad. Thank you :) I'm sorry that I still can't rate your answer because I don't reach the minimum score. Wait your solution :) Thank you

Comment: I was testing your code a bit. You deleted the columns in container-firstpage, so ok, I get the logic. I noticed, though, that I can add the columns in card text-bg-dark. Then write card text-bg-dark col-1 col-md-12. That way, everything still looks ok. What do you think about it? Thank you

Comment: Check the new solution.

Comment: It’s about knowledge, I am glad to know that I was able to help you. It would be great if you have any job opportunities for me :)

Comment: Not now, but in a few months maybe I have a job opportunity for a bootstrap news website. Let's keep in touch. Can you upvote the question so I can upvote your answer? (I have low score so far) Thank you

Comment: Can I get your LinkedIn? It’s fine if you cannot upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `col` and `col-auto` for the div. see below

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-pc {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-primapagina {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

.banner {
  text-align: right;
}

.height1 {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-pc">

    <div class="container-primapagina col">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner col-12 col-md-auto">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="col" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col-md-auto (Utility only for measuring) [will take 100% width for devices smaller than `md-width(&lt;740px)`]
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-pc {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-primapagina {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}



.height1 {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-pc">

    <div class="container-primapagina col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card text-bg-dark">
        <img src="https://siviaggia.it/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/02/grattacieli-new-york.jpg" class="card-img height1" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/tmCY8gW/ffffffffffff.png" alt="provabanner">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-pc">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color: aqua;" ;>Col 8 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: rgb(81, 255, 0);" ;>Col 4 (Utility only for measuring)</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to remove text-align right